# Doctrine 2.5.4 discriminator issue with postgres camelCased column name: "The discriminator column "" is missing for "" using the DQL alias "r"

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, discriminator, multi-table-inheritance

So I was working with doctrine multiple class table inheritance with an existing database. When I tried to query it throws

> The discriminator column "customertype" is missing for "Entity\Customer" using the DQL alias "r".

The current entity setup is as follows:

I have an abstract class Customer where the discriminator column is defined.

```
<?php
namespace Entity;

use {included all imports}

Entity\Postgres\Customer\CompanyCustomer;

/**
 * Customer
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     1="Entity\Customer\Merchant",
 *     2="Entity\Customer\Affiliate"
 *     })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repository\CustomerRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="public.`Customer`")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="customerType", type="smallint")
 * @JMS\Discriminator(field="customerType", map = {
 *     1="Entity\Customer\Merchant",
 *     2="Entity\Customer\Affiliate"
 *     })
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
abstract class Customer implements EntityInterface
{

    protected $id;
    more properties...
    and methods...
}
```

The child **Merchant** class...

```
<?php

namespace Entity\Customer;

use {included all imports}

/**
 * Merchant
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="public.`CustomerMerchant`")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Merchant extends Customer
{

}
```

The child **Affiliate** class...

```
namespace Entity\Customer;

use {included all imports}

/**
 * CustomerAffiliate
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="public.`CustomerAffiliate`")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Affiliate extends Customer
{
}
```

I know the problem is on the discriminator column having a camelCased and not quoted format but maybe anyone had the same problem and created a work around with this.

Comment: What it the actual column name in the database?

Comment: The actual column name is customerType